# how to back data from viewcontroller to tableview use delegate

Tags: swift

```
extension SecondViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, EditContactDelegate {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return contacts.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ContactTableView
        cell.contact = contacts[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let newVC = NewViewController()
        newVC.nameLabel.text = contacts[indexPath.row].name
        newVC.delegate = self
        newVC.numberPhoneLabel.text = contacts[indexPath.row].numberPhone
        newVC.avatarView.image = contacts[indexPath.row].avatar
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newVC, animated: true)
        
    }
    func editContact(name: String, numberPhone: String) {
        var contact:Contact?
        let nameEdit = name
        let numberEdit = numberPhone
        
        contact?.name = nameEdit
        contact?.numberPhone = numberEdit
        
        }
}
```

My data is not updating at tableview even though delegate works[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoHHu.png)

Comment: What is the screenshot for?

Comment: Please add code using the ‘{}’ button by editing the question. It’s the preferred method.

Comment: i updated it. help me

Comment: Where are you reloading your table view data?

Comment: There are two serious problems. If `NewViewController` was designed in a storyboard  then you get a new instance (**not** the storyboard one) without connected outlets. And even if you got the proper instance the outlets are not connected (yet) right after creating the instance. So your code crashes reliably.

Comment: tableView.reloadData() after line contact?.numberPhone = numberEdit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make variable selectedIndex and set value on did select method

```
    var selectedIndex = 0
    
    func editContact(name: String, numberPhone: String) {
        guard selectedIndex > 0 else { return }
        contacts[selectedIndex].name = name
        contacts[selectedIndex].numberPhone = numberPhone
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let newVC = NewViewController()
        newVC.nameLabel.text = contacts[indexPath.row].name
        newVC.delegate = self
        newVC.numberPhoneLabel.text = contacts[indexPath.row].numberPhone
        newVC.avatarView.image = contacts[indexPath.row].avatar
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newVC, animated: true)
        selectedIndex = indexPath.row
    }
```